# How to add color for every span element inside li by using css

Tags: html, css, frontend

Hi there i was trying to add different color for span element by using pseudo. can you help me with that

```
<ol class="hidden-xs">
  <li class="active dt-nav"><span class="dot-nav">1</span></li>
  <li class="dt-nav"><span class="dot-nav">2</span></li>
  <li class="dt-nav"><span class="dot-nav">3</span></li>
  <li class="dt-nav"><span class="dot-nav">4</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Can you share your CSS with us? How did you try to add the color? What was not working?

Comment: ol>li.dot-nav:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
ol>li>.dot-nav:nth-child(2) {
    background: black;
}

Comment: Maybe you should fix your HTML first. What is </i> for?

Comment: You could use inline css or [nth-child Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: sorry am new here were do i add css here

Comment: thanks everyone for your time , i've got it, this is community is fast

Comment: You have a stray `</i>` element inside the `li`. Is that suppose to be an icon?

Comment: yea i just modified before and forgot to remove, thanks have a great time @LGSon

Answer (score 2):

```
.dt-nav:nth-child(1) {
  color:red;
}
.dt-nav:nth-child(2) {
  color:blue;
}
.dt-nav:nth-child(3) {
  color:green;
}
.dt-nav:nth-child(4) {
  color:orange;
}
```

Comment: beat me on speed :) (class is .dot-nav)

Comment: I just checked recently

Answer (score 1):

use :nth-child()

```
li span:nth-child(1) {
  color: green;
}
li span:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
li span:nth-child(3) {
  color: blue;
}
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the correct li cholds to your css elements. For example:

```
ol.hidden-xs > li:first-child > span.dot-nav {
    color: #000000;
}

ol.hidden-xs > li:nth-child(2) > span.dot-nav {
    color: #333333;
}

ol.hidden-xs > li:nth-child(3) > span.dot-nav {
    color: #db0036;
}

ol.hidden-xs > li:last-child > span.dot-nav {
    color: #cccccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your css and use [proper selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp):

```css
ol > li.dt-nav:nth-child(1) > .dot-nav {
    background: red;
}

ol > li.dt-nav:nth-child(2) > .dot-nav {
    background: black;
}

ol > li.dt-nav:nth-child(3) > .dot-nav {
    background: red;
}

ol > li.dt-nav:nth-child(4) > .dot-nav {
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<ol class="hidden-xs">
  <li class="active dt-nav"><span class="dot-nav">1</span></li>
  <li class="dt-nav"><span class="dot-nav">2</span></li>
  <li class="dt-nav"><span class="dot-nav">3</span></li>
  <li class="dt-nav"><span class="dot-nav">4</span></li>
</ol>
```

Also your html is not well-formed (`</i>`).

Comment: It's working Thanks a lot, yea my mistake i forgot to remove </i> , thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You could try "nth-of-type" for each li item, like this:

```
li:nth-of-type(1) span { color: red; }
li:nth-of-type(2) span { color: white; }
li:nth-of-type(3) span { color: blue; }
li:nth-of-type(4) span { color: rebeccapurple; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with Sass:

```
$colors: orange, blue, red, green;

li {
  @for $i from 1 to 5 {

    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      span {
        $color: nth($colors, $i);
        color: $color;
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o6w613y3/1/